# First finish reading data from Firebase and then do something else

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So my problem is that empty array is returned because reading data from Firebase is not finished yet. I am using then method but it still executes everything inside then before.

```
var usersList = [];

const ref = firebase.database().ref()

ref.child('users').once('value').then(snap => {

    snap.forEach(childSnap => {

        const key = childSnap.key

        ref.child(`users/${key}/points`).on('value', function(snapper) {

            var points = snapper.val()

            usersList.push({uid: key, points: points})

        })

    })

}).then(function() {
    console.log(usersList)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `then()` itself is not a magical solution. You need to return a promise from within the callback, which your code is not doing. In this case you only want the final `then()` to be invoked once all the users are loaded, so you need to return a promise that only resolves when done.

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref()

ref.child('users').once('value').then(snap => {
    var promises = [];

    snap.forEach(childSnap => {
        const key = childSnap.key
        promises.push(
            ref.child(`users/${key}/points`).once('value')
        );
    });

    return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(function(snapshots) {
    return snapshots.map(snapper => {
       var points = snapper.val()
       return {uid: key, points: points};
    })
}).then(function(usersList) {
    console.log(usersList)
})
```

Comment: It seems like this line is invalid: `return Promise.all(promises); `

Comment: Can you explain what's invalid about it?

Comment: It was a syntax error, ")" was missing before this line.

Comment: Nevertheless I get this error message after running my script: `(node:14560) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: key is not defined`